# reload partial after clic a checkbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, partial, rjs

I find a way to submit information after clic on a checkbox.

```
<% remote_form_for @object do |f|  %>
<%= f.check_box :state, :label => @object.state, :onchange =>
'this.form.onsubmit()'%> <%end%>
```

I would like to update the view… but no chance with the helpers. Any idea how to make it active ?

```
page[:patentencart].replace_html :partial => 'partial'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 response :

```
<%= form_for @object, :remote => true do |f|  %>
<%= f.check_box :state, :label => @object.state, :onchange => 'this.form.submit()'%>
<%end%>
```

Change 'this.form.onsubmit()' in 'this.form.submit()'